# How does the amount of energy bound in the gravitational field of an object relate to the energy of the object?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

If I understand correctly, there is energy bound in a gravitational field, although acceleration of the body that causes the field is required to release some of that energy (in the form of gravitational waves).

Is there a fixed relation between the energy of an object and the energy contained in the gravitational field that the object gives rise to?

[Gravity, its field, is said to be a source of more gravity. If the relation of the energy of the object and the energy of its gravitational field is fixed, could the claim, that gravity is a source of gravity, be like a way of looking at things? If not, would the claim be more substantial? I do not have the required knowledge to express this correctly, it probably needs to be reviewed. Beg you pardon.]

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational potential energy (and, indeed, any form of potential energy) is an attribute of the relative configuration of a system of objects. It cannot be attributed to any single body within the system. So we can calculate the gravitational potential energy of two massive objects separated by a distance $d$ (relative to the gravitational potential energy of the same objects when their separation is zero) but we cannot say that this potential energy is a property of one object or the other.

Answer (score -2):

I have heard the same confusion before. Your only confusion is: if a body causing a space-time curvature, or gravitational field or simple gravity then where is the distribution of energy of the field? And if energy is somewhere outside where space -time is curved, then what about gravity of that energy? Gravity causing more gravity?

Answer is no. There is no energy distribution outside where space-time is curved. All of the curvature would be due to mass-energy distribution of the system, or if we're considering only one massive body which is causing the space-time curvature then the curvature would be due to that massive body only. No gravity can't cause more gravity.

Now if you imagine that the system is two body system then one's gravity would affect other and the gravitational potential energy due to their interaction would be stored on each objects but that extra energy would not cause anymore space-time curvature. No gravity can't cause more gravity.